# wso2 api gateway giving as a binary response for backend rest api xlsx file

Tags: binary, wso2, response, chunked-encoding, mediator

i am trying to integrate with wso2 api manager for backend xlsx download rest api.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGJry.png)

Comment: You need to mention your problem not just in the subject, but in the question content as well. And also better to add log output from different invocation to narrowdown the case.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are receiving a xlsx file as the response, can you try the `Send and Download` option in postman?

[image]